# Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Trailing data, error on laravel date format validation

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon, laravel-validation

In my laravel based application, when updating user accounts I'm trying to validate the birthday field. I have the following in my controller's update method

```php
$rules = [
    'date_of_birth'=>[
        'required',
        'date',
        'date_format:Y-m-d',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $age = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->diff(Carbon::now())->y;
            if($age < 18 || $age > 70) {
                $fail('Âge invalide. l\'âge devrait être 18-70');
            }
        },
    ]
];
```

So the date format has to be Y-m-d and the age range has to be between 18-70.

Following is my form field

```
<div class="col-md-6 ">
 {!! Form::text('date_of_birth', old('date_of_birth', $user->date_of_birth), array('placeholder' => 'Date of birth','class' => 'form-control txt_txt','id'=>'datepicker')) !!}
 <span toggle="#dob-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar field-icon toggle-dob"></span>
 {!! $errors->first('date_of_birth', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!}
 </div>
```

But whenever I tried to submit an invalid date format like, 18/12/1995, it kept giving me following error...

```
Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException
Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Trailing data
```

How can I fix this and validate the date format and display the error message properly.

Comment: You should be using `<input type="date"/>` which will ensure a consistent format is returned, and also lets web browsers use their built-in date pickers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's checking all of the validation rules at the same time, which means even if `Y-m-d` fails, it's still going to check your age limit. Add [bail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#stopping-on-first-validation-failure) to your validation rules so that it will stop validation on the first failure.

```
'date_of_birth'=>['bail', 'required','date', 'date_format:Y-m-d', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
```